# Need help with a symbol

Tags: notation

What does this notation mean?

$$
|i\rangle \langle j |$$

*Source of equation: Understanding the Physics Behind Topological Insulators Through
Su-Schrieffer-Heeger Model (https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08435)*

Comment: It is the "bra-ket" notation.  Google it.

Comment: Wikipedia has it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation

Comment: You can find a very good description of bra-ket notation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779194/what-is-bra-and-ket-notation-and-how-does-it-relate-to-hilbert-spaces)